# Как быть если яндекс карта загружает страницу в 2 раза медленее?

Tags: оптимизация-сайтов

Есть сайт, поставил карту от Яндекса, причем не через IFrame а через JS APi. Проблема в том что GTMetrix показывает скорость загрузки сайта без карты 4.2 с картой 8.1
Подскажите  пожалуйста как быть, карта очень нужна

Comment: К сожалению, законы физики (в частности, конечная скорость света) не позволяют картам загружаться мгновенно, смиритесь с этим

Comment: Понимаю но и за этого показатели сайта падают в 2 раза. А сервисы для SEO не хотят подключиться и за слишком долгой загрузки сайта

Comment: не добавляйте карту на страницу, пока область где она должна быть не показалась на экране